# Connect to Aurora RDS MySQL instance over AWS Direct Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53, amazon-rds

We have created an Aurora RDS MySQL instance in us-east-1 region that has public accessibility as "No". The RDS instance is inside of our VPC which is also connected with VGW for Direct Connect for the Private Subnets.

As per documentation, we created a Route 53 inbound resolver with the 2 private subnets and configured our internal DNS servers with the R53 inbound end-point IP addresses and a custom domain name like `env-dev.company.com`. Our VPC is using "DHCP Options Set" which contains the IP addresses of our internal DNS Servers. (Following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html) document)

We then created a Route53 private hosted zone with a CNAME record with name `db.env-dev.company.com` and the value set to the Aurora RDS endpoint i.e. `db.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`.

The above setup worked fine, and when we did `nslookup db.env-dev.company.com` it shows canonical name as the RDS Endpoint and the Address as the RDS instance's ENI Private IP. So the lookup is working. Our Lambda functions which are added to the VPC are also able to connect to the RDS Instance using the `db.env-dev.company.com` endpoint. However, we are unable to connect to the DB using `db.env-dev.company.com` through MySQL Workbench or a `mysql` client from our company network (developer laptops or servers).

When we turn the Public Accessibility to "On" it works, which is kind of expected, but isn't there a way to connect to a non-publicly accessible Aurora RDS instance via Direct Connect? I'd imagine that one of the benefits of having Direct Connect is to be able to access resources in the VPC from our on-premises network.

Comment: If you have DirectConnect you probably have a significant AWS presence, and likely AWS support. Their support is excellent and fairly quick even at developer level. Have you asked them? I guess I'd check that things are being routed over DC rather than the internet. I wonder if using a proxy would help.

Comment: Significant AWS presence yes! But our accounts are managed in a way that Support is an “Opt-in and pay” for individual depts/team and our Dept didn’t budget for AWS support for whatever reason. I think I might try the support forums. Yes, I know if the proxy EC2 instance solution but that kind of beats Direct Connect’s purpose and we don’t want to be paying for an EC2 just for proxy.

Comment: Get a team who does have support to send the query :) Interested in the result. Obviously the workaround is public database with a security group to prevent most access. Can you edit your question to add more information? Does you have a private VIF? Any kind of DC gateway? Can you ping EC2 instances running in the VPC by IP? Can you do an nslookup, over DC or over the internet? Basically put in configuration and troubleshooting work you've done. DC isn't widely used so not many people have experience with it, but hopefully someone here can help you.

Comment: Yes we use Private VIF. Yes EC2 can be pinged by IP and yes nslookup over DC for EC2 instances works fine too.